# ios to create view programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to create a view like the below one programmatically but it covers the whole screen and does not be like this. There could be some thing **size = Freeform**, but could not find code on google to handle this.

```
UIView *picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 260)];
    picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**Actually I want to create this whole view programmatically not though interface Builder.**

please help

[image]

Comment: No, there is no way, you will have to use `CGRectMake` to give size to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No other way than `CGRectMake`

if you want create the `UIView` that covers the whole screen

```
UIView *picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
picker.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview: picker];
```

if you want create the `UIView` that not covers the whole screen

```
UIView *picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 260)];
picker.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview: picker];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create UIToolBar which has UIBarButtonItem(=Done).
Set the UIToolBar as UIDatePicker's inputAccessoryView.

You don't even need a backgroundView to add Done button and date picker.